# Need help to calculate of CS and IP after a code of 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, emu8086

The question is:
If CS:1000H,IP:FF8A and Label1:DDH after reading JMP Label1 instruction,calculate contents of CS and IP registers after execution.

I am fairly new to assembly and dont know exactly how to calculate this.Can anyone explain?Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean `Label1` has offset `DDh` inside the same section the `jmp` is in?  Then it's a near jmp that doesn't modify CS, and reaches IP=00DDh via a relative jump.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp.  You could have tried this in the debugger built-in to emu8086 to see how jumps work.

Comment: Vehicle **V** goes from the city **A** to the city **B**. Where will it be when it arrives to **B**? 
After succesfull jump to **Label1** registers `CS:IP` will contain the address of this label. That's how `JMP` works.